# How can I get song metadata without using playUri using the Android SDK?

Tags: android, spotify, libspotify

I want to get song metadata from a URI without starting to play/buffer that song.

The only way I can see of doing it right now is calling playUri() and then getMetadata() but I don't want to play it immediately.

Is there any other way?

Thanks!

Edit: Is there a way to do this via the SDK with non-local files?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`MediaMetaDataRetreiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html):

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(context, uri);
String artist 
    = retreiver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
//etc
retriever.release(); //don't forget to call this when done
```