# Trying to get song metadata with Spotify Android SDK results in illegal argument exception

Tags: android, spotify, libspotify

I'm trying to get song metadata with the Spotify Android SDK without buffering the song. Here's my code:

```
public String getTitleFromURI(String uri) {

    //uri = "spotify:track:6ORqU0bHbVCRjXm9AjyHyZ"

    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

    Uri temp = Uri.parse(uri);

    System.out.println("URI: " + temp + "\n");

    retriever.setDataSource(uri); // java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

    return retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);

}
```

I'm unsure as to why I'm receiving an illegal argument exception.

Comment: The `retriever.setDataSource(...)` doesn't have a implementation that takes in a Uri object. See the interface [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)

Comment: It can take (String path) like in my example, or (Context context, Uri uri). I'm having no luck with any method. :(

Comment: good point! A good reason to remove dead code. Where is the stack trace?

Comment: Also this is expecting a file path name "Sets the data source (file pathname) to use. Call this method before the rest of the methods in this class. This method may be time-consuming." and not not a spotify type uri.

Comment: This? java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:188)

Comment: Edit: Yeah I get the same error providing it with context (this) and Uri (temp) too.

Comment: MediaMetadataRetriever would only work if you have a file, it will not work with Spotify URI strings. You might want to look the this [demo of the Spotify Android SDK](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/blob/master/samples/DemoProject/src/main/java/com/spotify/sdk/demo/DemoActivity.java) to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you sure? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233477/how-can-i-get-song-metadata-without-using-playuri-using-the-android-sdk

Comment: The only way to make  `MediaMetadataRetriever` to do what you want it to do is to download your spotify track, add it to your application, then use `MediaMetadataRetriever` to get the metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up using this: https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android

```
public String getTitleFromURI(String uri) {
    return spotifyService.getTrack(uri.split(":")[2]).name;
}
```

Thanks for your help!